# Create table as Select from another with Join?

Tags: mysql

I have a large table I am trying to update, I was told it is much faster to do a Create Table as (select). For instance if you wanted to update Field1 in a 10 million record table to UPPER it would (apparently) be faster to do

```
Create TableANew as (Select UPPER(Field1),Field2,FieldN from TableA); 
Drop Table TableA;
Rename Table TableANew to TableA
```

Assuming this is true, how would one do this is the updated field needs to be done as a join? In other words if my original plan was:

```
Update TableA as T1
Inner Join TableB as T2
On T1.Product=T2.Product
Set T1.ProductID=T2.ProductID
```

How can that update be incorporated into the Create Table as (Select from Table) structure? To be clear I used a very basic Create Table as Select to show the structure of that query as I understand it; I in fact need a Create Table as Select (Field,Field,Join) and am unclear how to set that up even in context of the first answer which, while providing improvements on the renaming of the tables doesn't address yet how / if I can do a join inside a Create as Select

Comment: IMO this is not the way to go. Do a normal update.

Comment: @juergen d So in your opinion no speed gain? The issue is that I am updating a 17 million record table and need to join that to a 40,000 record table.

Answer (score 0):

I am missing what a `join` is doing in the `update`.  The two approaches are:

```
update tableA
    set a.field1 = upper(a.field1);
```

versus:

```
create table temp_tableA as
    select upper(a.field1) as field1, field2, field3
    from tableA;

-- check, check, check that the data is right

truncate table tableA;

insert into tableA(field1, field2, field3)
    select field1, field2, field3,
    from temp_tableA;
```

Note:  You could use `rename` for the last two steps.  However, this approach maintains indexes, foreign key relationships, and triggers (and in other databases constraints as well).

The first approach is clearly simpler.  On large tables, though, logging the update transactions can be quite expensive.  In general, `create table as`, `truncate table`, and a large `insert` are faster than the updating.  Do note that this also avoids (for better or worse) any update triggers on the table.

Comment: My bad on making two incompatible examples. I was trying to show simply how a basic create table from table is from a basic Update/Join statement is. What I need to do is precisely what you say; avoid update transactions by using Create Table but the Update I need is NOT 'Upper'; I need to update a field in each record with data based on a relationship to another so I need the join. Right now I'm just running it as Update/Join but don't have too much faith in it happening anytime soon. BTW from my understanding it is best to REMOVE the indexes from the update table and add back.

Comment: @user3649739 . . . One can only answer the question that you ask.  I would suggest that you ask *another* question with more appropriate detail for your actual problem.  Revising this question could invalidate this answer, which in turn can draw downvotes, so it is rude.